# Change SQL server back to a trial

Tags: sql-server, product-key, sql-server-2008

I need to convert a SQL Server 2008 instance on a VM (which is licensed) back to a trial.

What are the steps to do this?

**REASON for this**: Need to give a VM with a custom solution on it to a 3rd Party. I need to remove our SQL Server License before giving it to them.

Comment: It is not the same

Comment: @Xavierjazz The questions are related, but are not duplicates as they pertain to different software.